# Xades signature creation and verification end-to-end working example?

Tags: java, xades4j, xades

I need Xades B-T signature creation and verification in a Java project. I found DSS and xades4j projects, but I'm unable to set them up. For example with DSS creating signature is easy, but during verification I get various errors.

Even DSS's official validation example [here](https://github.com/esig/dss/blob/master/dss-cookbook/src/test/java/eu/europa/esig/dss/cookbook/example/validate/ValidateSignedXmlXadesBTest.java) doesn't work, `simpleReport.getErrors()` gives:

```
[The certificate path is not trusted!, The result of the LTV validation process is not acceptable to continue the process!, The result of the timestamps validation process is not conclusive!, The certificate chain for timestamp is not trusted, there is no trusted anchor.]
```

I need an end-to-end working example covering:

- self signed key and certificates creation (I don't have a trusted certificate yet)
- Xades signature generation with the keys and certificates
- Xades signature verification with the keys and certificates